# Wordpress site suddenly not showing some DOM elements but mobile is fine

Tags: css, html

So today I discovered that my website's homepage https://olgupsikoloji.com is missing body elements. It is a WP site running on AWS Ubuntu and LiteSpeed with LSCache and Memcached.

The issue is: Some DOM elements right after title bar appear to be hidden, but they are there, just not visible. You can click on them or view hidden images by dragging them. All elements are there in HTML and you can select them with developer tools, but not visible.

Here's what I've done: Yesterday, I updated some of the texts in other pages (which are fine) and nothing on homepage.

Here's what I tried to troubleshoot:

- Bypassed Cloudflare
- Cleared LSCache
- Disabled all plugins
- Updated Wordpress
- Updated the theme
- Tested on multiple browsers except Safari
- Tested on Chrome for Android (no issues)
- Page Builder seems okay, no open tags or any broken element.

Also: Setting individual element's opacity to 1 doesn't help.

As far as I can tell, it's a rendering issue on Webkit browsers for desktop (?)

I appreciate all the help, it's been driving me crazy.

Comment: You have the `.tm-animation` class throughout your content which your theme is setting to 0 opacity, apparently so it can animate in. Why this animation isn't happening is something you'll need to ask your theme author for help with.

Comment: ...and you should check the Dev Tools console to see why the JS isn't reverting their opacity back to 1 - there's probably a script error that breaks things, so the portion that turns things back to `opacity: 1` never gets it's chance to run.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.